# how i can make windows server 2003 see some directory from UNIX-AIX?

Tags: unix, command-line, windows-server-2003, aix, file-sharing

how i can make windows server 2003 see some directory from UNIX-AIX ?
i want share files between windows server 2003 and unix aix 6.1

Comment: share files between windowsserver 2003 and unix aix 6.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Samba](http://www.samba.org) which allows file sharing between computers running Windows and computers running Unix. With Samba, you can set up network shares for chosen Unix directories which will appear in Windows as normal Windows folders accessible over the network.